# Same CSS is injected into HTML over and over again

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to load my SCSS files, but I see the CSS being repeated many times over in my HEAD section in the HTML.

I use `sass loader` and `postcss`

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Where is the `css` repeated?

Comment: In the HEAD section

Comment: is the img u are referring to as head ?

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly. The image shows how the same CSS get's injected multiple times in the HEAD section of my HTML file.

Comment: Your CSS looks normal but you should worry about repeating injected fonts.

Comment: No the CSS in the style tag between the fonts are identically. Basically I'm loading all my CSS 30 times or so

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you use different SCSS files you import all over your app. Do you import globals in those SCSS files? Something with common styles like fonts and base variables etc? If yes, you need to split them up.

If you use SASS/SCSS with webpack, you really have to make sure that everything you import does not output CSS, because it will not be deduplicated.

See this example:

*index.js*

```js
import './header.scss';
import './button.scss';
```

*header.scss*

```scss
import 'base';

.header { color: hotpink; }
```

*button.scss*

```scss
import 'base';

.button { font-size: 14px; }
```

*_base.scss*

```scss
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
```

The result of the above four files with webpack and sass-loader will be that the Google Fonts import is included twice. All SASS imports you do that point to another SASS file are *not* handled by webpack, so they are not deduplicated. We had this issue too in a large codebase but managed to fix it.

What you want to do instead is the following:

*index.js*

```js
import './global.scss';
import './header.scss';
import './button.scss';
```

*header.scss*

```scss
import 'varsandmixins';

.header { color: hotpink; }
```

*button.scss*

```scss
import 'varsandmixins';

.button { font-size: 14px; }
```

*global.scss*

```scss
// This file should include everything you need globally that outputs CSS.
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
@font-face {
    // your font definition here
}
```

*_varsandmixins.scss*

```scss
// This file on it's own should not output any CSS! Only variables and mixins!
$baseColor: #000;
$fontFamily: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
@mixin something($var) {
    rule: $var;
}
```

You can see in the example above that the contents of `global.scss` are only imported via JS, so they go through webpack and will be deduplicated. All imports done from inside a SASS context don't output any CSS, so there's no issue with duplicate CSS either.

In short: when using sass-loader with webpack, try to do as much importing in JavaScript. Only imports done in JS can be deduped by webpack. Imports done from inside SASS files should only import variables, mixins and other things that don't output any CSS.

Comment: Perfect, this fixed the slowness that resultet of the duplication. While I got rid of the style tags, I still have a lot of `link` tags (i assume these are the result of me colocating the styles for each of my react components, and requiring them for each).

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The link tags are a result of how style-loader works and aren't usually an issue. One tag for every SASS file required from a JS config. For production builds you should use ExtractTextPlugin and extract the CSS to an actual CSS file you can include, if it's a lot.