# Webpack imports the same styles multiple times

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack

I've noticed, that my webpack configuration imports the same styles into head `<style>` tag multiple times, when I @import styles in sass file.

[image: Imported Styles]

I think it's because of my global styles file, which looks like this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
@import '~material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite.scss';
```

I later import the styles in multiple other component style files:

```
@import 'global';
```

Is there some configuration that I've missed?
I thought I could import the global styles file in index.js file through import, but these imports must come first, and somehow I was not able to achieve that with webpack.

Comment: Try seperate your mixins/variables into a separate `.scss` which you can import in your global and your components separately.

Comment: I use variables provided by mdl (material design language) from their node modules package. I have no way of splitting that file unfortunatelly

Comment: Do they not expose the variables seperately? Check the node modules dir

Comment: Yeah, I only just realized, that they only provide variables/mixins, which won't compile into css, so it won't matter if they're imported multiple times.

I will have to configure webpack to remove the huge license comment though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same CSS is injected into HTML over and over again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941153/same-css-is-injected-into-html-over-and-over-again)

Comment: Why don't you import the other files from global instead of importing global in every file?

Comment: because I like when components each have their own separate style, and I don't have to maintain one file with lots of imports from different component locations. Also, I do not want to have huge files with styles mixed from different components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an issue with webpack, more with your use of CSS.
Since CSS assets are compiled statically, each stylesheet importing `global` has a copy in it.
You could use Less, and the `@import (reference) statement`, or if you prefer CSS then load it separately and don't import it every time.

Comment: Is the same thing achievable with sass?

Comment: Not that I know of. What I do with sass is only import scss files with variable definitions, since that's the only real reason to import anything in an app. Other than that, just import each (external) stylesheet in your main app or scss file.

Comment: OK, now that Iook at it, you're right. Maybe it's me using the import incorrectly in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've named the file `global.scss` instead of `_global.scss`. The underscore tells the transpiler that this is a partial and NOT to create a file for it.

Comment: And this is why I hate the web.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@import` by the new `@use` and everything should be imported once only

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Answer (score 0):

@import in Sass is being depreciated from 2022, but the new @use is meant to be the solution to this.

It appears to have downsides if you have a big filesystem that relies on global variables (colours, breakpoints, etc.), and although I have yet to get it working on my work system, if you have a smaller filesystem, it's definitely worth looking into @use and @forward.

It definitely looks like changing your @import to @use would fix your duplication issue.